# Designing Serial Port Class

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am creating wrapper static class around SerialPort.
My concern is, I will have an static initialize method
which will open the port.

Then different threads can start reading and writing to this port - I will have locks inside custom read and write methods of this wrapper class.

Then there will be a static deinitialize method which will close the port.

My question is: Is there some problem with such design? e.g. is it bad practice to keep the port open like this? (for long time?)

Comment: It is the other way around,  closing and re-opening a serial port causes many problems.  The worker thread that fires the events needs to exit first, you don't know when that happens.  Well, other than the Open() call failing.  There is also very little benefit to allowing another process to steal the port and making your program fail when you try to re-open.  Don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant Can you please explain in a little bit more detail what do you mean? I could not follow you. I am a little bit beginner in .NET

Comment: @HansPassant: So you suggest I open the port in my static method and keep it open?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would want to use a static class for this.
Use an object instance instead, possibly a singleton instance. 
This way, you don't need a static initializer and you can use the IDisposable interface to close the port. After all, there aren't really any static deinitializers in C#, and introducing statics will, as always, make it hard to decouple your clients.

Keeping the serial port open for a long time shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I find singleton cumbersome to use, also I am not well familiar with that concept. I can add manual Deinitialize static method which someone will call. That is not a problem. Please advise on my current approach. Thanks. If I use normal objects then when one object dies it will close the port, if other object in the mean time tries to write - it will throw (it will not open port say because at the time it checked if the port was opened or not - it was).

Answer (score 0):

Why not open the port and checks if the port is open? IF open --> use it/close it first and open again. And test the result before any functions use the port.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Check open port
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ser">Serial port</param>
        /// <param name="br">Baudrate</param>
        public bool CheckOpenPort(SerialPort ser, int br)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ser.IsOpen) { ser.Close(); }
                ser.Open();
                ser.BaudRate = br;
                Thread.Sleep(Op.WaitTimeOut);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: So before each custom read and write method I call this function you say?

Comment: this is just a way to make sure, that the connection/port is available before doing any read/write operations, the cost of making sure port is ready will outweighs the cost of catching exception during read/write. IMHO